# haproxy health check on https backend strange results

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I have the following haproxy backend configuration.
I'm surprised that in haproxy status page the check is reported as "L6ok".
Why Layer 6 and not Layer 7 ?

```
backend back:lb    
    option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www.domain.tld

    default-server ca-file my.ca inter 10s maxconn 50 maxqueue 10 ssl check

    server lb-01.{{ domain }} 10.10.10.30:443 weight 100
    server lb-02.{{ domain }} 10.10.10.31:443 weight 100
```

Comment: I am having a hard time finding any HAProxy documentation about the levels, I'm seeing a "layer4 check passed" when using `server ... ssl check no-check-ssl` and a "layer6 check passed" when using `server ... ssl check`.

Answer (score 0):

for information, I added the expected http return code (302):

```
http-check expect status 302
```

and now checks are reported in l7:

```
L7OK/302 in 12ms
```